# How to improve performance or Query Execution Time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

This is my Query which takes minimum 1 minute to execute on remote MySQL server.

```
select 
    a.z_companyid_pk 'z_companyid_pk',
    a.company_name 'Client',
    a.display_name 'Display_Name',
    a.z_parentcompanyid_fk 'Parent_Company',
    a.z_resellerid_fk 'Reseller',
    (select 
            company_name
        from
            company_mst
        where
            z_companyid_pk = a.z_resellerid_fk) 'Reseller_name',
    (select 
            if(count(*) >= 1, 'YES', 'NO')
        from
            webprofile
        where
            z_boxid_fk in (select 
                    z_boxid_pk
                from
                    box_mst
                where
                    z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk)) 'V1_Website',
    (select 
            if(count(*) >= 1, 'YES', 'NO')
        from
            webapp_mst
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'V2_Website',
    (select 
            if(count(*) > 0, 'YES', 'NO')
        from
            widget_mst
        where
            widget_status = 1
                and type in ('templated-menu' , 'menus')
                and z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Widgets_with_my_menu',
    (select 
            if(count(imagehtml) > 0, 'YES', 'NO')
        from
            image_mst
        where
            length(imagehtml) > 0
                and z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'HTML_menus',
    (select 
            max(login_datetime)
        from
            loginlog_mst a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
            contact_mst b ON a.z_contactid_fk = b.z_contactid_pk
        where
            b.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'LCI',
    k.z_boxid_pk 'DMB_Box_ID',
    k.box_name,
    (select 
            box_lastcheck
        from
            box_online
        where
            z_boxid_fk = k.z_boxid_pk) 'LCI_last_Checked_in_Date',
    (select 
            websitelink
        from
            company_profile
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Website',
    (select 
            company_email
        from
            company_profile
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Primary_Contact_Email',
    concat(a.company_address_line1,
            a.company_address_line2) 'address',
    (select 
            city_name
        from
            city_mst
        WHERE
            z_cityid_pk = a.z_cityid_fk) 'city',
    (select 
            state_name
        from
            state_mst
        WHERE
            z_stateid_pk = a.z_stateid_fk) 'Province',
    (select 
            country_name
        FROM
            country_mst
        where
            z_countryid_pk = z_countryid_fk) 'country_name',
    a.company_postalcode 'zip_postal_code',
    (select 
            telephone
        from
            company_profile
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'company_telephone',
    a.z_timezoneid_fk,
    b.timezone 'time_Zone',
    (select 
            facebooklink
        from
            company_profile
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'facebook',
    (select 
            twitterlink
        from
            company_profile
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'twitter',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 1
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Yelp',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 2
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Urbanspoon',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 3
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Trip_Advisor',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 4
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Citysearch',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 5
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Open_Table',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 6
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'ZAGAT',
    (SELECT 
            bizurl
        FROM
            user_settings us
                INNER JOIN
            asset_mst am ON (us.userid = am.userid)
        where
            us.isiteid = 32
                and am.z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'Zomato',
    d.z_contactid_fk 'Email_contact_ID',
    d.username 'Email_User_Name',
    d.contact_firstname,
    d.contact_lastname,
    d.status,
    (select 
            max(login_datetime)
        from
            loginlog_mst
        where
            z_contactid_fk = d.z_contactid_fk) 'last_login_date',
    (select 
            GROUP_CONCAT(groupname)
        from
            contact_group_mst
        where
            z_companyid_fk = a.z_companyid_pk) 'group_name'
from
    company_mst a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    timezone_mst b ON a.z_timezoneid_fk = b.z_timezoneid_pk
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    company_profile c ON a.z_companyid_pk = c.z_companyid_fk
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (select 
        v.z_contactid_fk,
            v.z_companyid_fk,
            w.username,
            w.contact_firstname,
            w.contact_lastname,
            if(contact_wtaccess = 1, 'Veryfied', 'Not Veryfied') 'status'
    from
        priviledge_mst v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contact_mst w ON v.z_contactid_fk = w.z_contactid_pk
    where
        w.type <> 'Staff') d ON a.z_companyid_pk = d.z_companyid_fk
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (select 
        z_boxid_pk, box_name, asset_mst.z_companyid_fk
    from
        box_mst
    INNER JOIN asset_mst ON (box_mst.userid_fk = asset_mst.userid)
    where
        asset_mst.status = 0
            and type = 'menubox') k ON a.z_companyid_pk = k.z_companyid_fk
where
    a.status <> 0
        and a.z_companyid_pk in (101089 , 104001, 103863)
ORDER BY a.company_name
```

Please help me by suggest some techniques or modifications or any tips that I can apply on this query to improve performance.

Comment: what about table structures, indexes on which columns? Execution plan for the query?

Answer (score 0):

Even without actual data, it will be difficult to identify actual issue. but you can check with below 2 approach-

1. where you are using sub-query in left join, pass z_companyid_pk in sub-query to reduce data set in sub-query.
2. remove sub-query and use left join simply.

Assuming you have checked and all required index will be there.

Answer (score 0):

The construct

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

performa poorly because there are no indexes on the tmp tables from those subqueries.  Turn them into JOINs to the tables if possible.  If not, then CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE for them and index the tmp tables.

`a` needs `INDEX(z_companyid_pk)` unless that column is already the `PRIMARY KEY`.

How many rows in the output?  I want to understand how much work the aggregations are subject to.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you expect and want missing data from the "right" table.

> and  type = 'menubox'

Which table is `type` in?

Pleas provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for priviledge_mst, contact_mst, company_mst, asset_mst, box_mst.  We need to check the indexes.